# Some posts are partially hidden on the mobile website in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, firefox

When an answer/question contains a code block, image, video or other content that consumes some width, the post becomes partially hidden on the mobile site in Firefox on small screens (such as mobile phones).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Firefox.
2. Visit a post with a code block (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25785574).
3. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on "mobile".
4. Resize the window to about 500px or less.
5. Observe that the right part of the answer gets clipped, and there's no way to show the clipped content.

Firefox (32.0; note that the text at the right is clipped, there's no way to reveal the content because the `.answer` container has an `overflow:hidden` style):

[image: screenshot of clipped post in Firefox]

Chrome and the Android stock browser (text is correctly wrapped):

[image: screenshot of wrapped text in Chrome]

Comment: This is probably a bug in Firefox.

Comment: This bug is also present on IE Mobile 11 (Windows Phone 8.1). It's annoying to have to constantly switch to the full version to be able to read the answers.