# Mobile site layout broken with posts containing videos on Android Chrome and Android stock

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, videos

When checking pages on a mobile with embedded videos, the text seems to overflow the box. There is also no horizontal scrollbar, thereby making reading the answer impossible (without switching to Desktop mode first).

Example page: [How do we know that the First Doctor was indeed the first?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65927/how-do-we-know-that-the-first-doctor-was-indeed-the-first)

Screenshot:
[image: Unreadable text]

Device: Samsung N7505, Android 4.4, Mobile Chrome 38.0.2125.114. Also broken within the stock browser as well.

Related:

- http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4922/mobile-site-layout-broken-with-posts-containing-videos
- [Some posts are partially hidden on the mobile website in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239237/some-posts-are-partially-hidden-on-the-mobile-website-in-firefox)

Comment: Actually, the side gets cut off on my phone too. I thought it was because I'm using an evil browser on an old dumb phone.

Comment: This is still happening