# Mobile view's fixed width hides text when code is used

Tags: bug, mobile-web, windows-phone

As one of the two users of a Windows Phone on Stack Exchange, I know we're not getting a native app ([until Windows Phone supports .iap](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/06/stack-exchange-podcast-65-the-word-has-two-meanings-you-see/) ;)), so I muddle along with Mobile View.

The fixed width, no resize, overflow hidden options used often result in text being hidden on the right hand edge if a code block is used.

I'm running a Lumia 1020 running at 768x1280.

An example of a page with this issue:

[How do I make it difficult  for users to make multiple accounts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83005/how-do-i-make-it-difficult-for-users-to-make-multiple-accounts)

[image: text overflow hidden]

Comment: "image to follow as mobile view doesn't offer image upload ;)", that would be a nice [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site)...

Comment: Heh, yep, and then "Fixed width emails are too small on my device"...

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be at least somewhat browser (and possibly device and font) dependent.  While I cannot reproduce this issue with [your example answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83005/how-do-i-make-it-difficult-for-users-to-make-multiple-accounts/83010#83010) in either Chrome or Firefox on my Android tablet, nor in the Firefox dev tools responsive design mode on my desktop, I *can* reproduce it in both Firefoxes (but *not* on Chrome) with [this answer of mine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/mass-deletion-of-spam-revisions-in-mediawiki/45486#45486) (where the actual culprit seems to be the image, and not the code).

Anyway, one aspect of the problem that I did find the cause for is the lack of overflow.  Basically, for whatever reason, the current mobile view style sheet contains the following conflicting rules (other non-conflicting styles trimmed for clarity):

```css
.answer-summary { overflow: auto }
.answer { overflow: hidden }
```

Alas, because these rules have equal specificity, the latter one (i.e. `overflow: hidden`) takes precedence.  This is what's causing any overflowing answers to be clipped, preventing them from scrolling sideways.

A simple quick fix would be to add the following, more specific CSS rule:

```css
.answer.answer-summary, .question.question-summary { overflow: auto }
```

This should at least allow you to scroll such overflowing answers sideways or zoom out to read them.

(I'd add this style to [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), but no mobile browsers that I know of support user scripts, so there's not much point.)

Comment: I've just noticed this [prior art](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239237/33051), and the answer in their question also fails on my phone...

Comment: The thing is, as we're the poor stepchild with [little or no love](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/06/stack-exchange-podcast-65-the-word-has-two-meanings-you-see/) it would be nice if the "fallback" we have actually worked for us ;)